# Magento Paypal Payment Pro - Is there a way to send store name or URL

Tags: magento, paypal

I am using Magento community edition 1.6.1 and running multiple stores on it. I want to pass store name,url or a tag to paypal so that when I look at the transaction details, it shows me which store the order came from. I have not found a way to configuration it using Payment Methods.

What is the best way to implement it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Typically Magento has **Store Id** prefix in the **Order Increment Id** number. For example order #100000001 would mean it was created on the Store with **Id** #1 (typically Main Store), #200000001 would lead to Store #2 and so on.

In the Transaction details **Order Increment Id** would be presented as **Invoice Id**. After you have the **Store Id** you can determine what store name it was by reviewing System->Manage Store config.